# Updating Store state don't change the view of lazy-loaded module?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ngrx

I have two modules A and B with single component in each module. Module A creates a State in the Store and can change it anytime by dispatching actions i.e when user enter some number in text box and hit enter, state (an object with a number property) gets updated to that number. Lazy-loaded Module B is getting that State using Selectors. First time, when lazy Module B gets loaded, its `ngOnInit()` method runs and get the State value but when the State gets updated from Module A i.e I enter another number in text box and hit enter, this time no changes occur in Module B, because Module B don't get refreshed(reloaded). The image shows what I am trying to say. Module B is `3, value 3` initially when I first time enter 3 in the text box and hit Enter. But after lazy module B gets loaded, Now if I enter 2 in the box and hit Enter, Module B do not change to `2, value 2`.

[image]

Please find the demo application [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jz63v9). Module A is App Module and Module B is Value Module in Demo Application.

Comment: Request to post of your Component/State/Reducer/Selector code. It will also be better to provide code which lazy-load your module B [i.e. routing?]. Without seeing the code it's not easy to provide the correct solution.

Comment: provide more code please, for example you have valueId and value, which one do you show in your html.

Also your conclusion is not right, it's just enough to subscribe to store in ngOnInit and as long as your component is not destroyed if data is changed your will receive the new data.

To help you better please create stackblitz sample

Comment: @RezaRahmati I've created Demo Application on Stackblitz. Link is given in question.

Comment: I just learn a new Angular concept, Hot Module Replacement (HMR), and I think it  will be the solution of above mentioned problem.